# How to push with a regularity elements in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of posts ids and an array of videos ids. I need to mix both to have something like "First is a video, then 3 normal posts then another video then 5 normal posts.. repeat... until the end. (ie : Video,normal,normal,normal,Video,normal*5 and repeat..)

My code works but how can i make it more clean and concise ?

````php
$a1 = $video_posts_arr;
$a2 = $standard_posts_arr;

$res = [];

$tc1 = count($a1);
$tc2 = count($a2);

$tc = $tc1 + $tc2;

$i1 = 0;
$i2 = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $tc; $i++) {
    // first video
    if (isset( $a1[$i1] )) {
      array_push($res,$a1[$i1]);
      $i1++;
    }
    // next 3 normals
    if (isset( $a2[$i2]) ) {
      array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
      $i2++;
      array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
      $i2++;
      array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
      $i2++;
    }
    // next video
    if (isset( $a1[$i1] )) {
      array_push($res,$a1[$i1]);
      $i1++;
    }
    // next 5 normals
    if (isset( $a2[$i2]) ) {
        array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
        $i2++;
        array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
        $i2++;
        array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
        $i2++;
        array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
        $i2++;
        array_push($res,$a2[$i2]);
        $i2++;
    }
}```
````

Comment: FYI, push accepts 2 or more parameters.  Alternatively, `array_splice()` comes to mind -- worth a look. What happens if one array runs out of elements before the other?

Comment: "**until the end**"  ...until the end of what?  Which array is dictating the length?  You never answered my request for clarification.   If the video array is too short, do you want to recycle it?  If the normal array is too short, do you simply want to end on a video? or just suddenly stop iterating?

Comment: @mickmackusa there are some clarifications : arrays aren't identical in length. standard_posts_arr will be ~100 elements and the video array ~15 elements. I don't want to recycle the video array. The result array should be exactly the sum of two. Thank you for having interest for my question!

Comment: Okay @emp my original script will ensure that all elements from both arrays are used.  When either array is "too long", those elements will be consecutively included at the end of the output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i make it more clean and concise ?

Here's what I think you should do...

Iterate on the video array and inject each video element into the standard post array at the variable positions without making any replacements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MKgQv))

```
$video_posts_arr = range('a','e');
$standard_posts_arr = range(1, 16);

$pos = 0;
foreach ($video_posts_arr as $index => $video) {
    array_splice($standard_posts_arr, $index + $pos, 0, $video);
    $pos += $index & 1 ? 5 : 3; 
}
var_export($standard_posts_arr);
```

1. Using the `$index` of the videos array spares having to use incrementation while iterating.
2. I am using a ternary expression with a bitwise condition to increase the `$pos` based on whether `$index` is odd.  I should express these variables to better explain what is happening. As shown in this [Demo](https://3v4l.org/5luQ7), these are the values generated as `$index` increases:

   > ```
   > $index = 0, $pos = 0; splicePoint = 0, isOdd = false
   > $index = 1, $pos = 3; splicePoint = 4, isOdd = true
   > $index = 2, $pos = 8; splicePoint = 10, isOdd = false
   > $index = 3, $pos = 11; splicePoint = 14, isOdd = true
   > $index = 4, $pos = 16; splicePoint = 20, isOdd = false
   > ```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 'b',
  5 => 4,
  6 => 5,
  7 => 6,
  8 => 7,
  9 => 8,
  10 => 'c',
  11 => 9,
  12 => 10,
  13 => 11,
  14 => 'd',
  15 => 12,
  16 => 13,
  17 => 14,
  18 => 15,
  19 => 16,
  20 => 'e',
)
```

The above script is demonstrated using a ratio of videos to standard posts which results in no consecutive videos.

If your video to standard post ratio is too great, then the above script will simply append all remaining/extra videos to the end of the standard posts array.

---

If you would like to ensure that the final element in your standard posts array is not a video, then you can add a conditional `break` like this:

```
$pos = 0;
foreach ($video_posts_arr as $index => $video) {
    $injection_pos = $index + $pos;
    if (!isset($standard_posts_arr[$injection_pos])) {
        break;
    }
    array_splice($standard_posts_arr, $injection_pos, 0, $video);
    $pos += $index & 1 ? 5 : 3; 
}
```

Or to allow a maximum of one video after the last standard post, move the `break` after the `array_splice()` call and account for the injected video element like this:

```
$pos = 0;
foreach ($video_posts_arr as $index => $video) {
    $injection_pos = $index + $pos;
    array_splice($standard_posts_arr, $injection_pos, 0, $video);
    if (!isset($standard_posts_arr[$injection_pos + 1])) {
        break;
    }
    $pos += $index & 1 ? 5 : 3; 
}
```

Comment: Your solution is more concise and cleaner than the one i first accepted and to be honest i can understand yours better. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of hard to tell from your wording, but I'm assuming you're wanting to go back and forth between 3 "regular" posts, then 5, then 3, etc, between each "video" post.  So as we loop through the video posts, we have to toggle back and forth between those options, and then use that plus a marker/counter to know where to insert each video post in the list of regular posts.

```
$a1 = array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5");
$a2 = array("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7", "p8", "p9", "p10", "p11", "p12", "p13", "p14", "p15", "p16");

$skipNum = 3;
$currentPos = 1;

array_unshift($a2, array_shift($a1));

foreach($a1 as $v)
{
    $currentPos+= $skipNum;
    array_splice($a2, $currentPos, 0, $v);
    $currentPos++;

    if($skipNum == 3)
    {
        $skipNum = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        $skipNum = 3;
    }
}

var_dump($a2);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b647249f6604c36db3f1afee3f0a6ee251abb80)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?
This solution uses [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to create result. This methods does not edit original arrays, just creates new one based on arguments.

```php
$a1 = array("v1", "v2", "v3");
$a2 = array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10");

$output = array_merge(
    array_slice($a1, 0, 1), //take one arg from a1. Not smartest to be honest but works. Maybe someone will give better idea here.
    array_slice($a2, 0, 3), //take first 3 elements from a2
    array_slice($a1, 1, 1),
    array_slice($a2, 3, 5),
    array_slice($a2, 300, 500), //it is save :)
);

print_r($output);
# [0] => v1
# [1] => a1
# [2] => a2
# [3] => a3
# [4] => v2
# [5] => a4
# [6] => a5
# [7] => a6
# [8] => a7
# [9] => a8
# [10] => a9
# [11] => a10
```

array_slice that takes only one argument `array_slice($a1, 0, 1)` looks bit cryptic but at least it is save to use.

This'll create new array instead of editing existing one. It comes with some additional overhead (You probably should not worry about it).

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b23381b31ab7ed48f1941cbca981071eaf250af